# I live in... a city/the city

Tags: articles

I can say:
I live in Prague.
I live in a city called Prague.
I live in the city of Prague.

But, can I also say:
I live in the city Prague.
I live in a city Prague.

Is it possible to say these two last sentences? I presume it is not. But if so, what is exactly mean.

Comment: It is clear what you mean in the last two sentences.  But neither would be spoken by a native English speaker.

Comment: "a city Prague" sounds wrong to me.

Comment: "the city Prague" is also awkward, "the city *of* Prague" is more idiomatic.